r markdown shiny html and word output
I want to provide a 'download word document' button to the user- they should have the ability to interact with the shiny dashboard of the markdown file but also choose the plots and download them in the word document. However, I'm not sure how to do this, I'm providing some examples as well- the last line of the code is for the user to choose which plot they like best, and whichever plot they choose should appear in the word document they download- is that possible?

title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    plots:
      align: center
date: "2024-05-29"
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

```

This R Markdown document is made interactive using Shiny. Unlike the more traditional workflow of creating static reports, you can now create documents that allow your readers to change the assumptions underlying your analysis and see the results immediately. 

To learn more, see [Interactive Documents](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html).

## Inputs and Outputs

You can embed Shiny inputs and outputs in your document. Outputs are automatically updated whenever inputs change.  This demonstrates how a standard R plot can be made interactive by wrapping it in the Shiny `renderPlot` function. The `selectInput` and `sliderInput` functions create the input widgets used to drive the plot.

```{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
  selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
              choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20),
  
  sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
              min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
)

renderPlot({
  hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
       xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser eruption duration")
  
  dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
  lines(dens, col = "blue")
})
```

## Embedded Application

It's also possible to embed an entire Shiny application within an R Markdown document using the `shinyAppDir` function. This example embeds a Shiny application located in another directory:

```{r tabsets, echo=FALSE}
shinyAppDir(
  system.file("examples/06_tabsets", package = "shiny"),
  options = list(
    width = "100%", height = 550
  )
)
```

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
library(plotly)

plot_ly(cars,type='scatter',mode='lines')%>%
    add_trace(x = ~speed, y = ~dist)
```




Note the use of the `height` parameter to determine how much vertical space the embedded application should occupy.

You can also use the `shinyApp` function to define an application inline rather then in an external directory.

In all of R code chunks above the `echo = FALSE` attribute is used. This is to prevent the R code within the chunk from rendering in the document alongside the Shiny components.

```{r echo=FALSE}
# Ensure the labels in selectInput match those expected in the server logic
selectInput("plotType", "Choose a plot type:", choices = c("Bar Plot" = "Bar Plot", "Pie Plot" = "Pie Plot"))

output$selectedPlot <- renderPlotly({
  # React to user selection and display the corresponding plot
  if (input$plotType == "Bar Plot") {
    plot_ly(diamonds, x = ~color, y = ~reorder(color , price), 
            type = 'bar', orientation = 'h')%>%
      layout(xaxis = list(title = "color"),
             yaxis = list(title ="price"))%>%
      layout(xaxis = list(ticksuffix = "%"))
  } else {
    plot_ly(diamonds,
        labels = ~color,
        values = ~price,
        type = 'pie',
        textinfo = 'label+percent',   # display labels and percentages on the chart
        insidetextorientation = 'auto') %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
  }
})

plotlyOutput("selectedPlot")
```


The closest I know to what you want to do is to download individual files from your markdown document using downloadthis R package.

Here is a draft approach which listens for plotly afterplot events and for each such event uses the plotly api to store the contents of the plot in a reactive value.
Because getting the plot source takes a few seconds, {shinyjs} is used to toggle the enabled state of the download button so that a download cannot be initiated when the reactive value is not ready.
---
title: "Save The Plotlies"
output: html_document
date: "2024-05-31"
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(base64enc)
library(officer)
library(plotly)
library(png)
library(shinyjs)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
useShinyjs(TRUE)

selectInput(
  "plotType", 
  "Choose a plot type:", 
  choices = c(
    "Bar Plot" = "Bar Plot", 
    "Pie Plot" = "Pie Plot"
  )
)

output$selectedPlot <- renderPlotly({
  if (input$plotType == "Bar Plot") {
    plot_ly(
      diamonds, 
      x = ~color, y = ~reorder(color , price), 
      type = 'bar', orientation = 'h'
    ) %>%
      layout(xaxis = list(title = "color"), yaxis = list(title ="price")) %>%
      layout(xaxis = list(ticksuffix = "%"))
  } else {
    plot_ly(
      diamonds,
      labels = ~color, values = ~price, 
      type = 'pie', textinfo = 'label+percent', insidetextorientation = 'auto'
    ) %>%
      layout(
        xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
        yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE)
      )
  } |>
  event_register("plotly_afterplot")
})

plotlyOutput("selectedPlot")

observe({ 
  plotly_afterplot <- event_data("plotly_afterplot")
  disable("download")
  runjs("
Plotly.toImage('selectedPlot', {
    format: 'png', 
    width: 600, 
    height: 600
}).then(function(dataUrl) {
    Shiny.setInputValue('plot_source', dataUrl);
});
")
  enable("download")
})

plot_source <- reactiveVal()

observeEvent(input$plot_source, {
  plot_source(input$plot_source)
})

disabled(downloadButton("download", "Download"))

output$download <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    sprintf("%s.docx", input$plotType)
  },
  content = function(file) {
    plot_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
    plot_source <- sub("data:.+base64,", "", plot_source())
    plot_source <- readPNG(base64decode(what = plot_source))
    writePNG(plot_source, plot_file)
    
    read_docx() |>
      body_add_img(plot_file, width = 6, height = 6) |>
      print(file)
  }
)
```


